# SQL Get interval last week (sunday to saturday)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a simple sql script where i can grab the rows with a date between sunday 2 weeks ago and saturday the previous week.

I need the query to return the elements no matter what day of this week I run the query.

Lets say I run the query today: Thursday 12. dec 2016. (12-08-2016)

I need to get this interval:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '11-27-2016' AND '12-03-2016'
```

Comment: What`s your database?

Comment: @Mihai Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: there's a whole variety of ways you could do it. one would be: `select cast(dateadd(week, -2, getdate() - t.num) as date) startDate, cast(getdate() - t.num - 1 as date) endDate from (values ('sunday', 0), ('monday', 1), ('tuesday', 2), ('wednesday', 3), ('thursday', 4), ('friday', 5), ('saturday', 6)) t(name, num) where datename(weekday, getdate()) = t.name`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @StartInterval DATE,
        @EndInterval DATE,
        @Today = GETDATE()

SET @EndInterval = DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(dd,-1*(DATEPART(dw,@Today)-1),@Today))
SET @StartInterval = DATEADD(dd,-6,@EndInterval)

SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE date BETWEEN @StartInterval AND @EndInterval
```

Comment: Note: This would generally work but requires your `datefirst` to be 7 (sunday, default, but not always this value).

Answer (score -1):

You can use:
select * from table where date between next_day(date, 'SUN')-21 AND
next_day(date, 'SAT')-14

Comment: next_day() is not a recognized function in MSSQL Server

Comment: I think you're thinking of Oracle.